# Access to the path '' is denied when i try to copy a Excel in specific folder vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i try to copy a file from the server on the specific folder when press a button, my code for copy the file are that:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("../../TempDownloads/" & SampleOrder & ".xls")) = True Then
            System.IO.File.Copy(Server.MapPath("../../TempDownloads/" & SampleOrder & ".xls"), "\\art-fs02\07_ART_ECO\12_Samples\03_Samples_order\999_MoraruVladutBOM_Test\" & SampleOrder & ".xls", True)
        Else
            LBL_Error.Text = "There is no file to be copied !"
            GC.Collect()
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

Ok, all good, i have two application with different referinces and differents imports, but at first application work to copy my file in specific folder ("\art-fs02\07_ART_ECO\12_Samples\03_Samples_order\999_MoraruVladutBOM_Test\") but when i try to another applicatiob files doesn't work. All two application are on server.

When i put the same code in page get me error like that:

> Access to the path
>   '\art-fs02\07_ART_ECO\12_Samples\03_Samples_order\999_MoraruVladutBOM_Test\Test.xls'
>   is denied.

I put a image with References for first application where my code work and references for second application and where doesn't work.

[image]

I don't know why on first application my code work, and copy the file, and the second application doesn't work.

I put all my code for page above:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports OfficeOpenXml
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration

Partial Class TCO_Orders_TestCopy
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim SampleOrder As String = "SO-Test"
        Dim Qty As String = "55"

        SampleOrder = SampleOrder.Remove(0, 3)

        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
        Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
        cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("../../FolderBOM/BOM2.xls") & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;""")
        cn.Open()
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "UPDATE [ARO list$] set info = '" & SampleOrder & "' where [SO-info] ='DVM SO no.'"
            cm = New OleDbCommand(.CommandText, cn)
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()

            cn.Open()
            .CommandText = "UPDATE [ARO list$] set info = '" & SampleOrder & "' where [SO-info] ='Local SO no.'"
            cm = New OleDbCommand(.CommandText, cn)
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()

            cn.Open()
            .CommandText = "UPDATE [ARO list$] set info = " & Qty & " where [SO-info] ='qty'"
            cm = New OleDbCommand(.CommandText, cn)
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()
        End With

        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
        Server.MapPath("../../FolderBOM/BOM2.xls"),
        Server.MapPath("../../TempDownloads/" & SampleOrder & ".xls"), Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
        Catch ex As Exception
            LBL_Error.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            LBL_Error.Text = "This SO has BOM created !"
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        If System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("../../TempDownloads/" & SampleOrder & ".xls")) = True Then
            System.IO.File.Copy(Server.MapPath("../../TempDownloads/" & SampleOrder & ".xls"), "\\art-fs02\07_ART_ECO\12_Samples\03_Samples_order\999_MoraruVladutBOM_Test\" & SampleOrder & ".xls", True)
        Else
            LBL_Error.Text = "There is no file to be copied !"
            GC.Collect()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a possible cause, but I would be sure to Dispose the connection before trying to use the file

Comment: I don't understand...how?

Comment: Just before the Try add _cn.Dispose_ or better add a Using/End Using all around the creation of the connection and before the Try _Using cn = New OleDbConnection("...._

Comment: Are you sure that the account under which asp.net is running has permissions to write to that location?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to make this a comment, but i don't have the Rep yet to comment, so i'm forced to make this an answer instead, but a lot of times when you get path access violations or file access violations a lot of times it can be the cause of invalid elevation and wont let you do any operations inside the specified path, if your trying to run it while in the editor you can always try running the editor in Admin Elevation that way it will elevate any processes made by it as well as the program your attempting to test, or you could just run it directly as Admin and see if it works properly, I've had this problem several times before and most the time it was solved by that.